# Unread Messages badge on iPad

Tags: ios, icloud, messages, notifications

I have a badge with two unread messages in the Messages.app on my iPad. Messages in iCloud is setup on all my devices. This two unread messages don’t show up on any of my other devices. I also can’t find this unread messages on my iPad.

What can I do? Is there a why to show all unread messages? Is there a way to reset Messages on my iPad?

Comment: Check FaceTime and make sure there's no unread calls.  Also, does this iPad have cellular connectivity?  In Messages, check `Unknown Senders` to see if there's a message there.

Comment: Checked everything you said. Yes, it does have cellular.

Comment: That's how I found the unread message when I had this issue.  Have you restarted the device?  Force-quit Messages.  Then do a force-restart of the device.  See if that helps.